# How can to merge value in if-else rule?

Tags: javascript, node.js, if-statement

```
key_brand = "a"
key_type = "b"
result = "a b"

if(key_brand key_type == result) {
True
}
```

I need to check value and output as "True"

So my question on this "key_brand key_type == result"

How can I write?

Comment: like you want both `key_brand` AND `key_type` to equal result?

Comment: `if (key_brand + " " + key_type == result) { ... }`

Comment: basic string concatenation...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the sample values you've shown, it sounds like you want to create a new, combined value (`key_brand + " " + key_type`) that you test against:

```
if (key_brand + " " + key_type === result) {
    // Yes, they match
}
```

Example:

```js
var key_brand = "a"
var key_type = "b"
var result = "a b"

if (key_brand + " " + key_type === result) {
    console.log("They match");
} else {
    console.log("They don't match");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to make an `Array` of the substrings and join with a `" "` or any desired string.

```js
key_brand = "a"
key_type = "b"
result = "a b"

if(Array(key_brand, key_type).join(" ") == result) {
        alert("match");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use es6 [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
if ( `${key_brand} ${key_type}` === result ) {
  // matches, so do stuff here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **ES6** [**Template Strings**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for string interpolation.

```js
let key_brand = "a";
let key_type = "b";
let result = "a b";

let key_brand_type = `${key_brand} ${key_type}`;

if(key_brand_type == result) {
  console.log(true);
} else {
  console.log(false);
}
```